# Default constraint on getdate() not working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE Emp 
(
    Empno number(4),
    Ename varchar2(20),
    Job varchar2(20),
    Hire_date date
);

ALTER TABLE Emp
    ADD CONSTRAINT df_date
        DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR hire_date;
```

> ERROR at line 3:
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Can not understand what is wrong here.

Please help!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-5652DBC2-41C7-4F07-BEDD-DAF620E35F3C

Answer (score 4):

`GETDATE()` is a SQL Server function for the current date, is not supported by Oracle.  You may use `sysdate` instead:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Emp (
    Empno number(4),
    Ename varchar2(20),
    Job varchar2(20),
    Hire_date date default sysdate
);
```